# Is it possible to tell if a Reddit bot using PRAW has already 'seen' a particular comment thread?

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

Basically what I would like to do is:find a keyword in a post, and count it using my bot. This part is done. However: I also have a separate part of the bot meant to count how many total threads the keyword appears in. This is where I have come unstitched. I can't work out the syntax for "grab the ID of the comment chain" I could probably get the comment ID itself, and I can definitely store it, but I have no idea how to track the number of comment chains.

If you could explain how in a way that is beginner friendly,, I would really appreciate it. I'm also trying to make the bot ignore sticky comments, which could contain whatever the keyword is and be posted dozens of times a day.

Comment: You probably need to keep track of which comments you've seen before using the comment ID. Look into [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)

Comment: Do you know how I would go about that? If it stores the comment ID, it likely won't do anything but stop it counting old posts. But I need to stop it counting entire threads.

Comment: Threads also have an ID, and you could store the thread ID in the same way as described before.

Comment: Really? Do you know how to do that? Is there a tutorial?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.